# Creating a wifi-hotspot on Broadcom BCM43142 network controller in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, broadcom

I have a laptop with Ubuntu that has Broadcom BCM43142 network controller. I intend to use my laptop as a wifi-hotspot. The available drivers for BCM43142 do not support creation of access points hence my attempts at creating a wifi access point have failed.

Is there any other way I can create a wifi-hotspot using my laptop like writing some short script and running it. If yes then, could somebody help me with that?

(PS: I wish to use the created wifi-hotspot on android devices and Kindle)

Answer (score 0):

There is no driver available to make BCM43142 as AP in linux.